# I need to get specific data from text file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have Some information in a string output which i am getting from

```
subprocess.Popen(['/bin/grep', '-E', 'CLIENTS', p ], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, encoding='utf-8')
```

when i print i am getting like below

```
CLIENTS='ip-10-161-110-51:ip-10-161-111-52:ip-10-161-112-53'
ISCSI_CLIENTS='ip-10-161-110-51,ip-10-161-111-52-227,ip-10-161-112-53'
NFS_CLIENTS='ip-10-161-110-51,ip-10-161-111-52,ip-10-161-112-53'
CLIENTS='ip-10-161-110-43:ip-10-161-111-42:ip-10-161-112-41'
ISCSI_CLIENTS='ip-10-151-108-51,ip-11-161-111-42,ip-10-161-112-41'
NFS_CLIENTS='ip-10-121-110-32,ip-10-161-111-34,ip-10-161-112-35'
```

How can i merge this to get the output as below

```
CLIENTS = ip-10-161-110-51:ip-10-161-111-52:ip-10-161-112-53:ip-10-161-110-43:ip-10-161-111-42:ip-10-161-112-41
NFS_CLIENTS = ip-10-161-110-51,ip-10-161-111-52,ip-10-161-112-53,ip-10-151-108-51,ip-11-161-111-42,ip-10-161-112-41
ISCSI_CLIENTS = ip-10-161-110-51,ip-10-161-111-52-227,ip-10-161-112-53,ip-10-151-108-51,ip-11-161-111-42,ip-10-161-112-41
```

Comment: This text file does not have any line breaks?

Answer (score -1):

Try using find on a string in python to get start and stop locations of wanted text in the string. You can then call that bit of the string out of the array like this.

```
    input_text = ""
    text_start = input_text.find("NODES")
    text_stop = input_text[text_start].find("# The") + text_start
    wanted_text = input_text[text_start:text_stop]
    print(wanted_text)
```

You can expand on this idea to find the exact starting locations by name such as "NODES" or "FILERA=ip" then search for an end character such as a ',' after to get each item separate from one another. I have made the code above grab the wanted batch of text that was given, you just need to feed the file output into where input_text is located in the code to set it up dynamically.